# Creating persistent variable in mysql(5.7)

Tags: mysql, database, variables, persistence

Good afternoon,

I am trying to create a variable in MySQL (5.7), that will persist through restarts. It appears that user created variables will not give me the ability to accomplish this so I am looking at the global variables. These appear to be built-in to MySQL and I cannot seem to find a way to create a new persistent variable.

How can I create a global/system variable in MySQL (5.7) that will persist through restarts?

Comment: Short of modifying the server source code, you can [create new system and status variables by writing a plugin](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/plugin-data-structures.html#plugin-status-system-variables)... but it seems worth asking... why?

Comment: @Michael I have some software that is hard coded to look for storage_engine but mysql 5.7 changed the variable to "default_storage_engine"

Comment: Oh, that sounds fun. `storage_engine` was deprecated quite some time back, but officially disappeared in 5.7.  Write a plugin, hack the server source, or find a way to fix that hard-coded app... pick your poison.  I think I have a book that may give an example of doing this.  I'll look.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot If you want to post that it is not possible without those three options you stated, I will go ahead and accept that as an answer :)

Comment: I found the book, Expert MySQL by Charles A. Bell, but the example I was thinking of was not exactly as I had remembered it.  I'll post an answer like you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no simple way through the SQL interface or configuration to create new system variables -- they are, after all, "system" variables.  Any solution to this that comes to mind would be an advanced operation, like one of these:

- modify the MySQL server source code to create a new system variable
- modify the MySQL server source code to reintegrate the "deprecated" logic from prior versions, where the old variable and new variable behave the same but the old variable throws a warning when you use it
- write a MySQL plugin (in C) whose only purpose is to [expose a new system variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/plugin-data-structures.html#plugin-status-system-variables), basically a dummy variable that doesn't actually do anything, other than having a default value and maybe being (or giving the appearance of being) writable if needed, in order to keep the application happy